# exec master..xp_cmdshell bcp create file only works on C:\ drive

Tags: sql-server-2012, bcp, xp-cmdshell

I am trying to create a formatted text file generated via stored procedure using xp_cmdshell bcp.  It works, but only on C:\ drive.  When I try to create the file on E:\ drive or a share drive, I get following error:

> SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0 Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13
>   for SQL Server]Unable to open BCP host data-file

I did make sure same folder structure existed on E:\ drive or a share drive, but no luck.  This same code works on a different server for E:\ drive as well.  I am not technical enough to figure out what could be different between two servers.

My code I am running in Management Studio / Sql Server Agent:

```
declare @sql varchar(1024);
declare @bcp varchar(1024);
Declare @DateSuffix char(8)
SELECT @DateSuffix = cast(convert(CHAR,GETDATE(),112)as varchar(8)) 
declare @filename varchar(1024)

set @filename = 'C:\Blackline\SB\GL_' + @DateSuffix + '.txt'
set @sql = 'exec VoyagerX.dbo.COPT_uspVOYtoBlackLine_GL_Extract'
set @bcp = 'bcp "' + @sql + '" queryout "' + @filename + '"  -T -c  -S'   

exec master..xp_cmdshell @bcp
```

If this information helps, I am using service account (I believe which is standard).  If this is permission or configuration issue, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, I needed to give full access to service account to a specific folder by right clicking and going through security.